# Directive causing infinite digest loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-digest

the following directive is causing an infinite digest loop and i am not sure why. any ideas on how to re-work the code?

thanks!

```
  .directive('fitHeight', ['$window', '$timeout', '$location', function ($window, $timeout, $location) {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: true,
  link: function (scope, element, attr) {
    scope.docHeight = $(document).height();
    var setHeight = function (newVal) {
      var diff = $('header').height();
      if ($('body').hasClass('layout-horizontal')) diff += 112;
      if ((newVal-diff)>element.outerHeight()) {
        element.css('min-height', (newVal-diff)+'px');
      } else {
        element.css('min-height', $(window).height()-diff);
      }
    };
    scope.$watch('docHeight', function (newVal, oldVal) {
      setHeight(newVal);
    });
    $(window).on('resize', function () {
      setHeight($(document).height());
    });
    var resetHeight = function () {
        scope.docHeight = $(document).height();
        $timeout(resetHeight, 1000);
      }
    $timeout(resetHeight , 1000);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$timeout(resetHeight, 1000)` is causing the `Infinite $digest loop`. This is because the method `resetHeight` is changing the variable `$scope.docHeight` and starting another `$timeout` cycle, `$timeout` triggers `$scope.$apply()`. Internally Angular watches for what may appear to be, or actually is, and endless `$digest loop`, if it finds this condition an exception is thrown.

I had to do something similar to what your working on, I will wont to do `Debouncing` logic on the `Window Resize` event. This is because the event is fired as the window is being resized. You will need to `throttle` the handler calls so that you wont have `$digest loops`.

In my example below, I am using Lodash for my Debouncing logic.

http://plnkr.co/edit/vUHcgpveDvijGE6l1LXy?p=preview

```
            angular.module('myApp', [])
                .directive('fitHeight', ['$window', '$timeout', '$location', function ($window, $timeout, $location) {
                    return {
                        restrict: 'A',
                        scope: true,
                        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                            function setHeight(newVal) {
                                var diff = $('header').height();

                                if ($('body').hasClass('layout-horizontal')) {
                                    diff += 112;
                                }

                                if ((newVal - diff) > element.outerHeight()) {
                                    element.css('min-height', (newVal - diff) + 'px');
                                    console.log('if');
                                } else {
                                    element.css('min-height', $(window).height() - diff);
                                    console.log('else');
                                }
                            }

                            setHeight($(document).height());

                            var docHeight = $(document).height();
                            var heightCheck = function() {
                                if (docHeight != $(document).height()) {
                                    docHeight = $(document).height();

                                    setHeight(docHeight);
                                }
                            };

                            var lazyHeightCheck = _.debounce(heightCheck, 200);
                            $(window).on('resize', lazyHeightCheck);

                            element.on('$destroy', function() {
                                $(window).off('resize', lazyHeightCheck);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }]);
```

Comment: thank you for the code. however when the page first loads the re-sizing is not happening.

Comment: @Marco Im sorry I forgot to make the first call, I fixed the example and added a live one for you to test.

Comment: also i was playing around with the debounce interval and 0 works as well. this was able to avoid any screen flickering

Comment: With all due respect but I guess the answer is wrong. `$timeout(resetHeight, 1000)` does not recursively call `resetHeight` but registers it to be called in one second. This is a common way of running code once per second.

I'm not sure what triggers the loop in OP but this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/rio3nuwdjM8DZErrWgBO?p=preview) is probably more true to the original code.

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop calling the resetHeight function inside the resetHeight function.  The infinite $digest cycle is side effect of that infinite loop.